# How to filter list that has date and retrieve only data within 7 days

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda

So I have this model:

```
Student Model

public int StudentId {get; set;}
public string StudentName {get; set;}
public DateTime EnrollDate {get; set;}
```

I also have a list of student Model which is something like

```
List<Student> listOfStudents = new List<Student>();
```

and inside that list there are 100 students detail and the enroll date.

What I do next is to sort the list into showing from the latest one to the oldest one.

```
listOfStudents.Sort((x, y) => DateTime.Compare(y.EnrollDate, x.EnrollDate));
```

and it's working. However, I am currently struggling in showing only the EnrollDate within 7 days from Today.

Comment: Do you have students with EnrollDate bigger than today? Do you want also students before and after today but in the 7 days limit?

Comment: Hi, thanks no bigger than today. Before Today but in 7 days limit. Thanks!

Comment: Can you write a function that takes a *single* date and returns true if it meets your condition, and false otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about breaking down the problem into 2 sub-problems?

#### Sub-problem #1

> showing only the EnrollDate within 7 days from Today

We only need `Student`s whose `EnrollDate` property is within 7 days from today:

```
var today = DateTime.UtcNow;
sevenDaysOldList = listOfStudents.Where(x => (today - x.EnrollDate).TotalDays < 7);
```

The subtraction of the two dates results in a `TimeSpan` with a [`TotalDays`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totaldays?view=netframework-4.7.2) property, which we can use to determine the number of days elapsed between the two dates.

#### Sub-problem #2

> sort the list into showing from the latest one to the oldest one.

We need to sort `sevenDaysOldList` by `EnrollDate` in descending order:

```
sevenDaysOldList.Sort((x, y) => y.EnrollDate.CompareTo(x.EnrollDate));
```

..which will sort the list in place. [`OrderByDescending`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=netframework-4.7#System_Linq_Enumerable_OrderByDescending__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__) is a good candidate for this (it returns a new ordered list implementing [`IOrderedEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iorderedenumerable-1?view=netframework-4.7)):

```
sevenDaysOldList.OrderByDescending(x => x.EnrollDate);
// and of course .OrderBy(x => x.EnrollDate) for ascending order
```

#### Combine #1 & #2

You can now combine the solutions of the two sub-problems into one. How you do it is at your own discretion. This is how I would do it:

```
var sevenDaysOldList = listOfStudents.Where(x => (today - x.EnrollDate).TotalDays < 7)
                                     .OrderByDescending(x => x.EnrollDate);
```

#### Update: question in comment

> How do I modify/sort the list that remove all the list less than "26 June 2018" ? So the list will only have data date greater than 26 June 2018. Any data with date before 26 June will be removed

You can initialize that date in a `DateTime` variable, and use it with [`List<T>.RemoveAll(Predicate<T>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=netframework-4.7#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_RemoveAll_System_Predicate__0__), to remove items in `sevenDaysOldList` which are smaller than that date:

```
var filterDate = new DateTime(2018, 06, 26);
sevenDaysOldList.RemoveAll(x => x.EnrollDate < filterDate);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have one more request. How do I modify/sort the list that remove all the list less than "26 June 2018" ? So the list will only have data date greater than 26 June 2018. Any data with date before 26 June will be removed

Comment: Hello ! Sorry disturb again. Umm, what if it's remove all the dates after 26 June 2018?

Comment: Surely this is easy to figure out.. switch `x.EnrollDate < filterDate` with `x.EnrollDate > filterDate` :)

Answer (score 4):

Conceptually, I think of LINQ a lot like SQL. You have the `SELECT` portion, which is your projection (i.e. what am I pulling out of this set of data?). If you omit the `Select()` clause from LINQ, you'll get the whole record vs. only a portion if you wanted to pluck out only pieces of it. You have your `WHERE` portion which is a limiter, or filter condition that when applied to the set pulls back only the records that satisfy said condition. And lastly, there are operations you can apply that affect the order of the returned set. That's where the `OrderBy()` and `OrderByDescending()` come into play. So lets map those concepts to the examples below

---

#### No `Select()`, but we do have a `Where()` and an `OrderBy()`

```
var then = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7); //One portion of our Where. More below
var sortedStudents = listOfStudents
  //Our predicate. 's' = the Student passed to the function. Give me only the students
  //where s.EnrollDate is greater or equal to the variable 'then' (defined above)
  .Where(s => s.EnrollDate >= then) 
  //We have no Select statement, so return whole students
  //And order them by their enrollment date in ascending order
  .OrderBy(s => s.EnrollDate);
```

When run, `sortedStudents` will be loaded up *only* with students (entire `Student` objects, not a projection) that meet our `Where()` criteria. The `Where()` function takes predicate that specifies our criteria. A predicate is simply a function that accepts a record from the set that we're filtering, and returns a `bool` indicating whether or not it should be included.

---

#### Let's change the filter by adjusting the `Where()`

```
//Notice we've changed 'then' from 7 days ago to a fixed point in time: 26 June 2018
var then = new DateTime.Parse("26 June 2018"); 
var sortedStudents = listOfStudents
  .Where(s => s.EnrollDate >= then) 
  //Still no Select(). We'll do that next
  .OrderBy(s => s.EnrollDate);
```

Just like before `sortedStudents` will have whole `Student` records, but this time it will only contain those enrolled *after* or *on* 26 June 2018, as specified by our predicate.

---

#### Let's add a `Select()`

```
var then = new DateTime.Parse("26 June 2018"); 
var dates = listOfStudents
  .Where(s => s.EnrollDate >= then) 
  .Select(s => s.EnrollDate);
```

Now we've changed it so that instead of pulling back a *whole* `Student` we're only plucking out the `EnrollDate`. Notice I've changed the name of the receiving variable from `sortedStudents` to `dates` reflecting the fact that it now only contains a list of `DateTime` objects.

---

You could still replace `.OrderBy()` with `.OrderByDescending()` to change the order.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have one more request. How do I modify/sort the list that remove all the list less than "26 June 2018" ? So the list will only have data date greater than 26 June 2018. Any data with date before 26 June will be removed

Comment: So you have to think of almost like you're writing SQL (not sure if you've done that). Whenever you're filtering a set, you'll do that in the `WHERE` clause. I'll update my answer with additional info.